# Should I cherry pick or checkout a commit to work on top of it in the gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit

A colleague of mine committed a code which is in Gerrit but not in the master. I would like to work on top of it.

Should I create a local branch and cherry pick his commit and work on top of it OR should I checkout his code and create a local branch and work on top of it.

Which one is the right approach?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "is in gerrit but not in the master"? 1. It was pushed/submitted to another branch 2. It was pushed to master but it wasn't submitted yet.

Comment: It was pushed to master but it wasn't submitted yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fetch and checkout his commit, which I call a nameless branch (a ref like `refs/changes/xx/yyyxx/1`), and then work on it. It doesn't matter if it's detached HEAD state or you create a local branch. After you make your commit, push to `refs/for/<branch>`. Your commit and his will be dependent.

Update:

It's okay to cherry-pick his commit and then work on top of it if you don't care about the history, since the file contents of the final revision will be the same in both ways. The difference lies in the branch history. If you checkout his and then work on top of it, the history will be linear. At least the part around the commits of you two is linear. If you cherry-pick his and then work on top of it, you will see two branches merged. One is your local branch and the other is his local branch. They are diverged. The cherry-picked commit on your branch is redundant. Someday in the future when someone sees the history, he may be confused and ask why both of you made changes to the same chunks.

Besides, there could be a potential risk that may annoy you since you are using Gerrit. When you cherry-pick his commit, a new commit will be created. The two commits have the same commit message including the `Change-Id`. Your colleague has pushed his, and yours will be prevented by Gerrit if his is alreday submitted/merged, because Gerrit doesn't allow a second commit with the same `Change-Id` to be pushed to the same branch in this case. If his is still open, then yours will amend his as a second patch set. But I'm afraid your Gerrit also forbids one from amending the commit of others. Even if it allows you to amend his commit, it's not expected. Anyhow, it will either fail or behave improperly. So far as I know, it's very frustrating, especially when others are pushing you to get it done as soon as possible.

Comment: Just curious, Why not cherry pick and work on top of it?
Thank you for your quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

1) Go to your colleague change on Gerrit

2) Click on Download > Checkout > "Copy to clipboard" button

3) Execute the copied command in your local repository

```
git fetch https://USER@GERRIT-SERVER/a/REPO-FULL-PATH refs/changes/CHANGE-NUMBER/CHANGE-PATCHSET && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

4) Create a local branch to manage your work

```
git checkout -b LOCAL-BRANCH
```

5) Make your changes

6) Add and commit your changes

```
git add .
git commit
```

7) Push to Gerrit to review

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

Note: your change is dependent of your colleague change. If he/she push a new patchset (to fix some review issue for example), you'll need to rebase your change to the new patchset. If he/she abandon the change, you'll need to abandon yours or rework it based on master. Avoid to work based on pending changes, if possible, always prefer to work based on merged ones.

Comment: Thank you, Marcelo Ávila de Oliveira.
Just one more question, As I am a newbie to git and Gerrit, When is the right time to use a cherry pick and pull options from the download options.

Comment: You use these options to bring changes made in OTHER branches to yours (ex: bring changes from branch master to branch release). Cherry-pick redo a commit and pull merge it.